# Image not showing on Android App

Tags: java, android, image

I am trying to get a jpeg from a url and place it in an image view in my android app. I am using a method that turns an image from the url into a drawable. However, the image is not showing up, the image view is just blank

Here is the link to the jpeg: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/PT05_ubt.jpeg

Method:

```
public static Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) {
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
        return d;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Main function:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
    ImageView profilePhoto = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.personImage);

    String url = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/PT05_ubt.jpeg";

    profilePhoto.setImageDrawable(LoadImageFromWebOperations(url));
}
```

Comment: If you haven't already, throw in a log or debug it to make sure you're not getting an exception in `LoadImageFromWebOperations`. Also, make sure that you are able to see the ImageView if you use something local (say, making your own drawable) to make sure there isn't some layout issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an AsyncTask, since you have to connect to the internet to get the image:

So put this inside your activity :

```
ImageView profilePhoto = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.personImage);
 new LoadPictureAsyncTask(MainActivity.this, profilePhoto).execute();
```

And add this subclass:

```
public class LoadPictureAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {       
    private Context context;        
    private ImageView myProfPic;        

    public LoadPictureAsyncTask(Context mycontext,ImageView ProfPic){
        this.context = mycontext;           
        this.myProfPic = ProfPic;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {       }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        try
        {

        URL imageURL = new URL("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/PT05_ubt.jpeg");
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageURL.openConnection().getInputStream());
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
             bitmap = null;
        }                               

        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result)
    {                   
        if(result!=null)
            {                               
                myProfPic.setImageBitmap(result);               
            }           
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, im at beginner at this. Would this be the correct implementation?

Comment: LoadPictureAsyncTask async = new   LoadPictureAsyncTask(this,profilePhoto);

        async.doInBackground();

Comment: I didn't see the first two lines of code you wrote. Works perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, they weren't there, I updated it, glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) instead.

With Picasso, it's only one line of code to load an image into an ImageView from a URL.

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

Comment: Do you know how I would implement picasso? It looks really useful, but I don't know how to put it in my project. Thanks

Comment: If you're using gradle just add this line to the dependencies section in build.gradle
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you load it in a Bitmap:

```
URL url = new URL("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/PT05_ubt.jpeg");
Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
profilePhoto.setImageBitmap(bit);
```

Comment: i tried using the bitmap method before, but the app crashed. Do you have an idea why that would happen?

Comment: You might be doing too much work on the UI thread, you can create an Asynctask like @El_Mochiq proposes